# Multi-column layout with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can I achieve a multi-column layout like the following with bootstrap?

[image: layout]

I know something like the following would be easily possible due to the row/column layouting system but I purposely included an advanced example above to see if its possible...

[image: easy]

Comment: The height should be constrained like illustrated? Could that be fixed values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely achieve it using Bootstrap only. This kind of design just requires proper nesting of divs. Checkout the below exmple--

**Working Snippet**

```css
.border {
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: blue;
  margin-top: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-lg-2">
<div class="border col-lg-12">
section A<br>
section A<br>
section A<br>
section A<br>
section A<br>
section A<br>
section A<br>
section A<br>

</div>
<div class="border col-lg-12">
section B<br>
section B<br>
section B<br>
section B<br>

</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-8">
<div class="border col-lg-7">
section C<br>
section C<br>
section C<br>

</div>
<div class="border col-lg-5">
section D<br>
section D<br>
section D<br>
</div>
<div class="border col-lg-5">
section E<br>
section E<br>
section E<br>
section E<br>
section E<br>
section E<br>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-7">
<div class="border col-lg-12">
section F<br>
section F<br>
section F<br>
</div>
<div class="border col-lg-12">
section G<br>
section G<br>
section G<br>
</div>
</div>
<div class="border col-lg-12">
section H<br>
section H<br>

</div>
</div>



</div>
</div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: I have used `col-lg-*` classes only , so go full screen to watch it.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if you are comfortable using JavaScript, you can use masonryJS https://github.com/desandro/masonry

with only CSS it's not possible to make it unless the height is fixed, which i don't think will be the case since I guess you're looking for responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting fixed height value and adjusting float value too?